# Strapi upload image that'll update a field in the database for v4

Tags: strapi

let's say I have an events collection type that has an `image` property. How can I upload an image on strapi so that it'll upload and set it as the value for `events.image`?

This is the code that seems to work in v3 but not v4

```js
e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("files", image);
        formData.append("ref", "events");
        formData.append("refId", evtId);
        formData.append("field", "image");

        const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/upload`, {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
        });
```

When I upload an image there is no change for the event row in the database and I have no idea what's wrong. It successfully uploads it, but it doesn't change the value in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
formData.append('ref', 'api::event.event');
```

This is from the documentation for v4 which the changed how they reference their database entities  - https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/upload.html#upload-entry-files

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem you can use "plugin::users-permissions.user:" for example:

```
const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('files', image)
    formData.append('ref', 'plugin::users-permissions.user')
    formData.append('refId', 'events')
    formData.append('field', 'image')
    formData.append('source', 'users-permissions')
```

Based on this [url](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/11919#issuecomment-1088346614)

Answer (score 0):

Use Axios. It is the one and only option to do this.

```
const [file,setFile] = useState();
var data = new FormData();
data.append(
  "files",
  file // useState that call after input fild change and assign this function to input field => onChange=((e)=>setFile(e.target.files)
);
data.append("field", "banner");
data.append("refId", "29");
data.append("ref", "plugin::users-permissions.user");

var config = {
  method: "post",
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  url: "http://localhost:1337/api/upload",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    Authorization:
      "your api key",
  },
  data: data,
};

axios(config)
```